# Finding rows where two columns together don't equal predetermined values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe that I'm trying to find rows in which two columns, together don't match.

For example, `column:landing_page` could equal `new_page` or `old_page` and `column: group` could equal `control` or `treatment`. Currently I use

`no_line_up = df.query('group = treatment and landing_page = old_page or group = control and landing_page = new_page')`

I'm trying to find rows where `new_page` and `treatment` don't match.

but it throws and error. What's the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`pd.DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) you still need to use the same basic operators, e.g. use `==` to test for equality and use parentheses to separate conditions:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['treatment', 'control', 'hello'],
                   'landing_page': ['old_page', 'new_page', 'test']})

res = df.query('(group == "treatment" and landing_page == "old_page") \
                 or (group == "control" and landing_page == "new_page")')

print(res)

       group landing_page
0  treatment     old_page
1    control     new_page
```

More readable is to combine Boolean masks and use [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m1 = (df['group'] == 'treatment') & (df['landing_page'] == 'old_page')
m2 = (df['group'] == 'control') & (df['landing_page'] == 'new_page')

res = df.loc[m1 & m2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is

```
df.loc[((df['group']==df['treatment'])|(df['landing_page']==df['old_page']))&((df['group']==df['control'])|(df['landing_page']==df['new_page']))]
```

Comment: Thank you! However, group and landing_page are the columns old_page, new_page belong under the landing_page column. Treatment and control belong under the group column. Due to this, it throws an error.